# How to handle redirects with MODx's URL rewriting?

Tags: apache, .htaccess, url-rewriting, modx-evolution

The new website I created using MODx Evolution has different filenames and URL structure from the old site. I have to redirect the old URLs to the pages in the new site.

I tried different solutions I found in different forums, but it seems that MODx's URL rewriting is interfering with my rewrite rules.

Does anybody know how to handle this appropriately?

Answer (score 0):

I found a different solution inside of MODx to resolve the problem. I created a plugin in MODx which is hooked to the event "OnPageNotFound". There I use an array which holds the old urls as key and the new ones as array. The script selects the new url based on the old url in the key. Then I use the new url as the location for the new location in the PHP header.